# Iterating over dictionary by skipping the first key-value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have defined a dictionary with a key and a dataframe, like this

```
data = {'Value':[0,1,2,3,4]}
kernel_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['M0','M1','M2','M3','M4'])
my_dict = {'dummy':kernel_df}
```

And `my_dict` is later filled with appropriate data. Next, I want to iterate over the dictionary starting from the second key, because the first (index 0) is dummy and I want to skip that. If I use

```
for key in my_dict:
```

Then the first key is also read. If I use

```
for i in {1..len(my_dict)}:
    df = my_dict[i]
```

I receive the following error

```
    for i in {1..len(my_dict)}:
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'len'
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: "First key" or "second key" has no intrinsic meaning in a dict…

Comment: You could do `for key in list(my_dict)[1:]`, but which key will be omitted isn't necessarily predicable.

Comment: If you want to omit `dummy`, then explicitly omit `dummy`: `for key in (k for k in my_dict if k != 'dummy'):`…

Comment: Unless you're using an OrderedDict, you can't be sure what the "first" key will be. It will not necessarily be the first key that you added to your dictionary. Notwithstanding that problem, your *for* loop syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary doesn't have an inherent order(well okay, things [changed in Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html) where they now [maintain the order of insertion](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html).

However, you still can't index a dictionary like you would index a list.
(Okay you can get close to that kind of behavior if you really so wished, but I'll address that towards the end).
In your case, you can just iterate through the keys and skip the key if it's 'dummy' (or whatever you've defined it as).

```py
for key in my_dict:
    if key != 'dummy':
        do your thing
```

Perhaps a better alternative would be to simply remove the 'dummy' key once you know your dictionary has bee populated with proper values.

Now, coming back to getting the 'first key' because one is a >= Python 3.7 user:
Okay if someone really wanted to rely on the technical implementation of a version specific feature, they could probably do something like this:

```py
for idx, key in enumerate(my_dict.keys()):
    if idx != 0:
        do your thing
```

This is far from idiomatic code though, so really, you shouldn't.